# How to set my current location on a map using bool val=gmap.MyLocationEnabled;

Tags: android, google-maps

i am trying to run the follwoing code but GoogleMap.MyLocationEnabled returns a null value. can anyone help me in initializing it to true.

```
 _mf = MapFragment.NewInstance(op);
    fragTx.Add(Resource.Id.frameLayout1, _mf, "map");
    fragTx.Commit();
    bool val=gmap.MyLocationEnabled;
    val = true;
```

Answer (score 0):

```
googleMap.setMyLocationEnabled(true);
```

Comment: when i try to use it,intellisense syas android.gms.maps.googlemaps does not contain a definition for setMyLocationEnable   P.S:I am trying to build it using xamarin(c#)